# What does sed -e "s/\x01//g" do?

Tags: bash, shell

I have sed -e "s/\x01//g" in my code. I've noticed that without it, sort -u isn't removing all of the duplicate values but when I apply sed -e "s/\x01//g" and then do sort -u, only uniques remain. So I'm just wondering what sed -e "s/\x01//g" does.

I suspect there's some invisible characters because if I paste the file to BBEdit and then create another file, then sort -u performs as expected.

Thanks.

```
cat basel_segment.csv

2019-05-25 123.87
2019-05-26 128.81
2019-05-26 128.81
2019-05-27 131.64
2019-05-27 131.64
2019-05-28 142.41
2019-05-28 142.41
2019-05-29 131.47
2019-05-29 131.47
2019-05-30 140.27

cat basel_segment.csv | sort -u

2019-05-25 123.87
2019-05-26 128.81
2019-05-26 128.81
2019-05-27 131.64
2019-05-27 131.64
2019-05-28 142.41
2019-05-28 142.41
2019-05-29 131.47
2019-05-29 131.47
2019-05-30 140.27

sed -e "s/\x01//g" basel_segment.csv | sort -u

2019-05-25 123.87
2019-05-26 128.81
2019-05-27 131.64
2019-05-28 142.41
2019-05-29 131.47
2019-05-30 140.27
```

Comment: `\x` prefixes hex values, 1-32 of which are unprintable, so it is removing that value

Comment: Exactly right; `\01` is the ASCII digit with ordinal 1.